# Why Facebook Messenger bot publish is not happening?

Tags: facebook, bots, webhooks, facebook-messenger

Am Developing Facebook Messenger bot, Its working fine for my test users who are added as testers in Roles option in dashboard.

I have put my messenger bot for review. its not happening, reviewer messege say's "We received no automated response when we messaged your Page. Please ensure your experience is working as intended and resubmit".

Please help me out.

I am getting this error from last 10 days.

Comment: Any update on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Facebook app is live, go to you Facebook app dashboard, navigate to app review and turn on the first option to make your app live.
Remember, Facebook reviewers are considered "public" and the Messenger bot won't work for them unless the app is live.